# Multiply two fields together in django

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following query:

```
sales_for_date_for_provider.exclude(sales_or_return='R').values_list('royalty_price', 'conversion_to_usd'))
```

Is it possible to multiple the `royalty_price` * `conversion_to_usd` in the query? Or do I need to do a list comprehension or dive into raw SQL?

Comment: can you change the accepted answer please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) and specify `select` argument:

```
sales_for_date_for_provider.extra(select={'result': 'royalty_price * conversion_to_usd'})
```

The result would contain a `QuerySet` where each object would have an attribute `result` containing the multiplication of `royalty_price` and `conversion_to_usd` fields.

Comment: How would I then get the sum of those results? The following query does not work, as it doesn't recognize the column result: `sum(sales_for_date_for_provider.exclude(sales_or_return='R').values_list('result').extra(select={'result': 'royalty_price * conversion_to_usd'}))`

Comment: @David542 try to put `values_list` after the `extra`: `sales_for_date_for_provider.exclude(sales_or_return='R').extra(select={'result': 'royalty_price * conversion_to_usd'}).values_list('resul‌​t')`.

Comment: If you're passing it to `sum` you might want `flat=True` as well.

Comment: Here is what worked: `sum(sales_for_date_for_provider.exclude(sales_or_return='R').extra(select={'result': 'royalty_price * conversion_to_usd'}).values_list('result', flat=True))`

Comment: Django plans on deprecating this method.  Please provide a different, more acceptable solution.  I would if I could, but I am trying to find the same answer.

Answer (score 12):

The Django documentation [warns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#extra) us that the `extra()` method will soon be deprecated. Since I came upon this answer when searching for a similar question, I thought I'd share an alternative approach using Django's [built-in expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#built-in-expressions), specifically the `F()` object.

In response to the original question, you could achieve the desired outcome with the following:

```
sales_for_date_for_provider.annotate(
    result=F('royalty_price') * F('conversion_to_usd'))
```

[From the documentation:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations)

> F() can be used to create dynamic fields on your models by combining different fields with arithmetic:

And here's another example taken from the documentation that further illustrates its usage:

```
company = Company.objects.annotate(
    chairs_needed=F('num_employees') - F('num_chairs'))
```